# Can't get values from App.config file (framework 4.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, app-config

i have a config file like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?

configuration

  appSettings

    add key="PortName" value="COM4"

    add key="BaudRate" value="9600"

   add key="DataBits" value="8" 

  appSettings

configuration
```

... and then i want to access app.config values with this code:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.IO.Ports;

using System.Configuration;


namespace SystemToControler

{

    public class ConnectionProtocol : IConnectionProtocol
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

        public ConnectionProtocol()
        {
            serialPort.PortName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortName"];
            serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaudRate"]);
            serialPort.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBits"]);
        }
    }
}
```

... and it tells me i that those keys does not exist.

What am i doing wrong??? Please help!

Comment: What you are doing seems fine! What kind if app is this? Web / Windows forms etc?

Comment: Are you sure you have an app.config ? More precisely, a file named [yourAppName].exe.config in your app folder ? Or a web.config for a web based app ?

Comment: Errr... what do you mean by "this is a class file" ?

Comment: You'll need to fix the XML, it is unusable as-is.  Use the Code Sample tool in the editor toolstrip.

Comment: emmm... this app is a windows form, but this code that i posted in a project that only contains simple class files. This class is later instanted in win form class file.

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 projects ? Be sure to put your config in the right app.config, i.e. the winform project's app.config

Comment: it works now. I replaced the config file in the win form project and it works!!! :)

but i don't get it. why does it needs to be in a win form project, if i'm using config values in some other project?

thanks again Cédric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess inferred from comments: be sure to put your config in the app.config of the running app. Configuration from other projects are never read.

example:
If you have a solution with 2 projects, ClassLibrary1 with an app.config and Winform1 with its own app.setting, and Winform1 depends on ClassLibrary1, building Winform1 will give a directory with those files:

ClassLibrary1.dll

ClassLibrary.dll.config

Winform1.exe

Winform1.exe.config

When Winform1.exe is running, the configuration is read from Winform1.exe.config, all other configuration files are useless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider getting application configuration from within your winforms project and instantiating your `ConnectionProtocol` object from there as well. Your current method couples your `ConnectionProtocol` class to application configuration classes it doesn't need.

For example, in your application, do this:

```
string portName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortName"];
int baudRate = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaudRate"]);
int dataBits = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBits"]);

ConnectionProtocol protocol = new ConnectionProtocol(portName, baudRate, dataBits);
```